# why do I get a locale error even though it is set?

Tags: utf-8, ubuntu-14.04, locale, bitbake

When I run `bitbake`, I'm getting the following:

```
$ bitbake core-image-base
Please use a locale setting which supports utf-8.
Python can't change the filesystem locale after loading so we need a utf-8 when python starts or things won't work.
```

even though my locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, why is this?

```
$ echo $LC_ALL
en_US.UTF-8
```

For additional background information, please also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626916/how-to-set-locale-correctly-manually/626919

**UPDATE:**

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

My `~/.bashrc` looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

and when opening a new shell I get:

```
$ bash
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Comment: What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: @tink please see **UPDATE** above

Comment: So, what does `/etc/default/locale` look like? :)  And what distro are you on?

Comment: @tink `/etc/default/locale` does not exist and I'm on `Ubuntu 14.04` (I know it's EOL but the locale should still not be a problem!)

Comment: Can you please run `sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8;
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales ` and see whether this fixes it?

Comment: @tink Yep, it seems like this did the trick! Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: Sweet =} ... one is glad to be of service!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the "comment crowned by success" an answer:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 9):

If the shell existed before you added the locale, then you need to open a new one (either running `bash` as a child, opening a new terminal, doing a new ssh,...)

Then this should work.

```
$ export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
$ bitbake core-image-base
```

The export might not be needed, that depends on the default for your system.

Comment: Thanks for coming over here Eduardo! I've added some more details regarding my `~/.bashrc` on top